# echo variable result in quotes BASH

Tags: bash

I have a bash script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
pavadinimas=$1
pavadinimas2=${pavadinimas::-4}
echo "#!/bin/sh
mysql -uUSER -pPASSWORD -DDatabase -e 'UPDATE boom SET count = count + 1 WHERE Failo_vardas="$pavadinimas"';
vlc -f --play-and-exit /var/www/html/uploads/$pavadinimas" > /var/www/html/script/"$pavadinimas2.sh"
```

And I'm having problem with this line:

```
mysql -uUSER -pPASSWORD -DDatabase -e 'UPDATE boom SET count = count + 1 WHERE Failo_vardas="$pavadinimas"';
```

As you see I want to add the variable to quotes, but It comes out without It. I tried a lot of combinations to solve this out, but I failed. Lack of experience :/

Script result:

```
#!/bin/sh

    mysql -uUSER -pPASSWORD -DDatabase -e 'UPDATE boom SET count = parodymai + 1 WHERE Failo_vardas=name.mp4';
    vlc -f --play-and-exit /var/www/html/uploads/gaidys.mp4
```

I want to echo the variable in quotes like this:

```
mysql -uUSER -pPASSWORD -DDatabase -e 'UPDATE boom SET count = count + 1 WHERE Failo_vardas="name.mp4"';
```

Comment: Escape the quotes you want to use e.g. `WHERE Failo_vardas=\"$pavadinimas\"`.

Comment: @Gavin damn, I forgot about "\" character.... Thank you so much! Can you add this as a answer so I could accept It?

Comment: Your script is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: @Chepner any advices how to protect It? I'm new on these things, just making a project for my self, for learning purpose. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't use `bash` for such projects. Use a language with a proper SQL library that allows parameterized query, instead of dynamically constructing SQL commands with string operations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are really close. You just have to escape the quotes that you want to use.
e.g. `WHERE Failo_vardas=\"$pavadinimas\"`

Answer (score 1):

You have to leave the single quoting or your variable won't be evaluated.

So insert a single quote after the double quote, put your variable to evaluate, and re-insert a quote after your variable. Where the single-quoting ends, your env. variable will be evaluated instead of being treated literally.

Demo:

```
$ pavadinimas=name.mp4

$ echo 'UPDATE boom SET count = count + 1 WHERE Failo_vardas="'$pavadinimas'"';
```

result:

```
UPDATE boom SET count = count + 1 WHERE Failo_vardas="name.mp4"
```